# Selecting the right technique to predict disease from symptoms

Tags: machine-learning, algorithm-request

I'm trying to come up with the right algorithm for a system in which the user enters a few symptoms and the system has to predict or determine the likelihood that a few selected symptoms are associated with those existing in the system. Then, after associating them, the result or output should be a specific disease for the symptoms.

The system is comprised of a series of diseases with each assigned to specific symptoms, which also exist in the system.

Let's assume that the user entered the following input:

```
A, B, C, and D
```

The first thing the system should do is check and associate each symptom (in this case represented by alphabetical letters) individually against a data table of symptoms that already exist. And in cases where the input doesn't exist, the system should report or send feedback about it.

And also, let's say that `A` and `B` were in the data table, so we are 100% sure that they're valid or exist and the system is able to give out the disease based on the input. Then let's say that the input now is `C` and `D`, where `C` doesn't exist in the data table, but there is a possibility that `D` exists.

We don't give `D` a score of 100%, but maybe something lower (let's say 90%). Then `C` just doesn't exist at all in the data table. So, `C` gets a score of 0%.

Therefore, the system should have some kind of association and prediction techniques or rules to output the result by judging the user's input.

Summary of generating the output:

```
If A and B were entered and exist, then output = 100%
If D was entered and existed but C was not, then output = 90%
If all entered don't exist, then output = 0%
```

What techniques would be used to produce this system?

Answer (score 10):

I think you're coming at your problem slightly wrong... what you're essentially talking about is a belief network.

You may want to look into existing Bayesian Learning techniques to get your head around this, but belief networks commonly use the exact scenario you're talking about; using a set of known (or uncertain facts) statements to produce some inferred probability of a particular output.

Even more, they often express this through disease-symptom based examples in tutorials! Try [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.124.2195&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

My point is that it would be better to use a belief network as the theoretical groundwork is all already there for you, instead of an ANN.

Comment: If you want to implement a bayesian network from scratch, you're going to have to understand the raw mathematics that drive them. There are a couple of suites out there to run bayesian networks on without having to understand all of the (somewhat confusing at times) maths, such as Netica (https://www.norsys.com/netica.html)